# Using a schema stored in a JSON file in Python

Tags: python, google-bigquery

As to Google documents I can use the schema stored in a JSON file in command line as the following:

```
bq --location=location load \
--source_format=format \
project_id:dataset.table \
path_to_data_file \
path_to_schema_file
```

where `path_to_schema_file` is the path to the file that contains the schema

is there a way to do this in python and pass the schema from the json file to the `LoadJobConfig().schema` ? or I should read the schema manually and transform it into `bigquery.TableSchema()` object?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`schema_from_json()` seems to be [what you're looking for](https://googleapis.dev/python/bigquery/latest/generated/google.cloud.bigquery.client.Client.html?highlight=schema#google.cloud.bigquery.client.Client.schema_from_json).

It converts a file in json format to a list of `schema` properties (which seems to be [what you need](https://googleapis.dev/python/bigquery/latest/generated/google.cloud.bigquery.job.LoadJobConfig.html?highlight=schema#google.cloud.bigquery.job.LoadJobConfig.schema) for `LoadJobConfig().schema`)

Answer (score 0):

did you try initializing the `LoadJobConfig` with the schema ?

e.g.:

```py
with open('path_to_schema_file') as json_file:
    schema = json.load(json_file)
    LoadJobConfig(schema=schema)
```

Comment: actually this didn't work as LoadJobConfig.schema only takes list of SchemaFields() and doesn't take json

Comment: I thought it accepts a dict, because according to the [docs](https://googleapis.dev/python/bigquery/latest/generated/google.cloud.bigquery.job.LoadJobConfig.html#google.cloud.bigquery.job.LoadJobConfig.schema) , the type of `schema` can be a sequence of mappings